# What's the meaning of this dialogue about trees in The Hateful Eight?

Tags: dialogue, the-hateful-eight

What's the meaning of the following dialogue in *The Hateful Eight*?

> "...for no more a reason than to give a n**** a run for the trees."
>   "I made them trees."

I can't figure out what the word 'trees' is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first line, Chris is saying that Marquis committed murder and arson to give himself the opportunity to escape.  "A run for the trees" means the run you make when you escape somewhere and are trying to reach concealment, as in the woods.

"I made them trees," is Marquis saying "Well, my plan succeeded.  Because I did escape."  In other words, "I made *it to the* trees."